# Adding HTML5 query selector to browsers dont't support it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I'm using [HTML5 selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) aka `querySelector` all the time. Those selectors are really easy to use and handful. If you're not familiar with this API it's pretty much similar to jQuery selector API they get a CSS selector string and select right elements. For example these selectors works same:

```
jQuery('#div') == document.querySelectorAll('#div')

jQuery('.myClass a') == document.querySelectorAll('.myClass a');
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySe) of this API is pretty good. IE8 supports them. The only two browsers that don't support this API is IE7 and IE6. I'm looking for solution to add this functionality to IE7 and IE6. For me `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` is enough but if there was a way to implement more functions it would be great!

I started looking into [jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js), they did it before so it would be good place to see how they created the selector API but I didn't understand the code. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use the original [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) engine which jQuery uses (written by John Resig, author of jQuery).

Here's Sizzle's own description:

> A pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine designed to be easily dropped in to a host library.

---

If you want to be sure that you don't use `Sizzle` if `querySelectorAll` is natively supported (even though Sizzle will always use `querySelectorAll` when available), use this:

```
if ( ! document.querySelectorAll ) document.querySelectorAll = Sizzle;
```

Comment: +1 Sizzle is what I use when I need just a selector engine and don't already have jQuery and it's the engine inside of several framwworks.  Sizzle is smart enough to use several native selector functions when they exist and implement them itself when they don't.

Comment: how you implement with querySelectors? I mean it would be used if developer uses querySelector and there is no query selectors supported in browser. Mainly I want a fallback. The reason I would prefer using query selector is it's faster and have better syntax.

Comment: Cool, you're right. It use querySelector if available. Your answer has chosen as correct answer. :) Thanks

Comment: as @jfriend00 has already pointed out, Sizzle will always fall back to querySelectorAll when available. If you insist on doing it your way, see my amendment...

Comment: Now my problem is I can't find it gzipped anywhere. It's 307KB!

Comment: sizzle.js is 42kB and packed it's 12kB. The download from sizzlejs.com also contains test files etc. Gzip is performed by your webserver, so don't look for something like sizzle.gzip.js. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is usually a bad idea to use complex selectors to find elements as it tightly binds the script functionality to the layout and presentation of the document. A simpler strategy should be employed, such as using ids, classes or grouping elements in the document.

If you do that, then analyse your requirements, you may find you only need a couple of simple selectors. In that case, the standard DOM methods of accessing elements may do 90% of the job and you just need to add a bit of filtering. e.g. '#id' is just getElementById (which is what jQuery/Sizzle actaully uses for that selector), and '.myClass a' can use a fairly simple getElementsByClassname function (most browsers have one built in) with a filter for A elements.

Of course such functions could first test for qSA support and use it if available.

Note also that there are a number of live document collections already avaialbe that can be very efficient to use, and also the early DOM collections (such as getElementsByTagName) were live too. I'm pretty sure the qSA returns static collections because that's what javascript libraries with selectors had been doing.

Anyhow, food for thought.

Comment: What about `document.getElementById('bigDiv').getElementsByTagName('li')` `instead of document.querySelectorAll('#bigDiv li')` ? I feel you resist to new technology

Comment: I feel your attention span is lacking. Perhaps the line **Of course such functions could first test for qSA support and use it if available** should have been in bold.